# How is data partitioned and distributed among datanodes in MapReduce?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I'm new to MapReduce, I'm having the task to process large data(lines of records). One thing I should use is the **line number** of specific record in my mapper, and then reducer process the line number information based on the mapper.

For instance, suppose now I have an input.txt that is very large， each line looks like this：

```
1. Melo, apple, orange
2. orange, perl
3. apple, banana, car
...
10000. Apple
...
```

What if I want to cacluate the occurency of Apple in terms of its occurency line number, then to cacluate the relationship between these different fruits, like:

```
Apple => orange
```

Can I make the value in key/value pair like a list of line numbers.  But since I've no idea how the data is partitioned for different datanodes, then the line number information of the original input file will get lost. I don't know how the data is distributed among the datanodes, is it based on the offset from the first record? Or the size of the partitioned data?

I have looked up several tutorials and I am still confused about the exact workflow of mapreduce. In addition, I'm planning to use Amazon elastic mapreduce and use Python.

Maybe I'm talking about same thing in this discussion, but as far as I know, there's no solution at that time or during that discussion. Is it right?

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/current-line-number-as-key-td2958080.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on in your question, so I'm going to handle the chunks I understand. Here goes:

> I don't know how the data is distributed among the datanodes, is it
>   based on the offset from the first record? Or the size of the
>   partitioned data?

Data is distributed entirely based on size of the file. HDFS is does not know about your record boundaries and will simply break a file into blocks of a specified size (default 64MB). Then share those blocks among the cluster's DataNodes.

> I have looked up several tutorials and I am still confused about the
>   exact workflow of mapreduce. In addition, I'm planning to use Amazon
>   elastic mapreduce and use Python.

There's currently two major versions of Hadoop. The 1.x series AKA MapReduce v1 and the 2.x series AKA YARN. As a programmer, you'll interact with these in a similar fashion but under the hood there is some difference in how the work gets done. This is a common cause of confusion. Particularly, since most tutorials are for MapReduce v1.

> Maybe I'm talking about same thing in this discussion, but as far as I
>   know, there's no solution at that time or during that discussion. Is
>   it right?

So here's your data set:

```
1. Melo, apple, orange
2. orange, perl
3. apple, banana, car
...
10000. Apple
...
```

You've got a line number, a space, and then comma separated values. So it appears that you have a very different problem than what you've linked to in your question. Or do I not understand the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the [Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html) class.  The default is `HashPartitioner`.

http://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Custom+partitioner

Comment: As far as I know, the partitioner class is used in the procedure of reducer? What I'm confused is how the big data is distributed among many data nodes

Comment: `Partitioner` controls the partitioning of the keys of the intermediate map-outputs.
When you talk about data nodes are you referring to the actual object or something else? http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/DataNode

Answer (score 0):

You would not need to care about how to data are distributed across the data nodes. Hadoop will take care of that. You can basically treat it like any Linux file system. Although one huge file is chopped up into many blocks and stored in a distributed manner, when you run a MR job on that file, the job will processed on all the blocks related to the file.

For example, input.txt is a huge file that you have uploaded into HDFS.

```
hadoop fs mapper.py reducer.py input.txt output.txt
```

MR will basically run mapper.py on the blocks of input.txt on the data nodes, then pass the intermediate results from mapper.py(s) to reducer.py.

Your mapper.py should look something like this:

```
def mapper():
  for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.strip().split('.')
    index, items = data

    for item in items:
    print "{0}\t{1}".format(item, index)
# Result will look like:
# Melo  1
# Apple 1
# Orange 1
# Orange  2
# perl  2
```

I guess that this might be what you will need after the mapper.

Still thinking about the reducer... Basically the my idea for reducer will be to produce something like this:

```
Apple    1,3
Orange   1,2
Melo     1
perl     2
```

The result from reducer can be be used for correlating two items, which will need another reducer script which take run through the entire list to find the two stated item and see if they have the same index on the second field.

Comment: So suppose now I want to have line number for each record in the input.txt, the program will still be same like before(not parallel one)? This is weird for me, since data nodes only get part of the data, how could it determine these data's line numbers?

Comment: It is a bit vague for me to understand what you are trying to do. Maybe an example of the input data and the outcome will help

Comment: I modified the question, hope this will clarify my confusion. Maybe I'm not familiar with mapreduce, can it perform work like this?